# Fixed floor in Sprite Kit Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, collision, sknode

I can't seem to get a unmovable fixed floor / wall in Sprite Kit.

I have a scene which has an SKNode as a "floor" and when the user presses the screen, a block drops from the touched position onto the "floor". That works well, but when the user adds another lets say 20 blocks or so, suddenly the floor rotates.
This is the code for my Floor:

```
SKSpriteNode *floorNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.size.width*2, 10)];
floorNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), -5);
floorNode.name = @"floor";
floorNode.zPosition = 1;

floorNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:floorNode.size];
floorNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
floorNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
floorNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

return floorNode;
```

Sorry i'm quite new to Sprite Kit. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

EDIT: I've added some images to make the problem a bit more clear. Since it happens in this screen also. Those black spheres you see are flying from left to right like a canonball. I increased the amount of spheres to show the problem occurring. This is the code:

```
- (SKNode *)newEditButton {
    SKLabelNode *editButtonNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"chalkduster"];
    editButtonNode.text = @"EDIT CASTLE";
    editButtonNode.fontSize = 19;
    editButtonNode.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    editButtonNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 110, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 30);
    editButtonNode.name = @"edit_button";
    editButtonNode.zPosition = 2;

    editButtonNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(140, 40)];
    editButtonNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    editButtonNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    editButtonNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    SKAction *hover = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveByX:0 y:6.0 duration:0.9],
                                           [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-6.0 duration:0.9]]];
    SKAction *hoverForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:hover];
    [editButtonNode runAction:hoverForever];

    return editButtonNode;
}

- (SKNode *)newPlayButton {
    SKLabelNode *playButtonNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"chalkduster"];
    playButtonNode.text = @"SLAUGHTER";
    playButtonNode.fontSize = 19;
    playButtonNode.fontColor = [SKColor darkGrayColor];
    playButtonNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 110, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 30);
    playButtonNode.name = @"play_button";
    playButtonNode.zPosition = 2;

    playButtonNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(140, 40)];
    playButtonNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    playButtonNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    playButtonNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    SKAction *hover = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveByX:0 y:6.0 duration:0.9],
                                           [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-6.0 duration:0.9]]];
    SKAction *hoverForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:hover];
    [playButtonNode runAction:hoverForever];

    return playButtonNode;
}
```

After a while 5-10 seconds, the "buttons" called "slaughter" and "edit castle" start to rotate everytime a sphere collides with it. But it doesn't seem like it has to do something with physics, because, if it rotates to the left, it's rotation direction will always be left. And if it starts rotating right, it's rotation direction will always be right[image: before rotation].[image: after rotating started]

It looks funny though! But not what i want ;-)

Comment: Have you tried +(SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:(CGRect)rect? An edge has no volume or mass and is always treated as if the dynamic property is equal to NO. Edges may only collide with volume-based physics bodies.

Comment: You mean like this:
floorNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:floorNode.frame];

That doesn't seem to make any difference. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I've edited my question to clear things up a bit

Comment: make the labels edge loops too

Comment: Doing so removes the rectangle around the labels, so no collision is possible. Also, adding edge loops to the floor didn't make any difference, however the labels are SKLabelNodes while the floor is just a SKNode.
But neither work correctly using edge loops.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know it, but you're telling SpriteKit to apply collisions from the cannonballs to the labels, and from the blocks to the floor!

That's because you're leaving SKPhysicsBody.collisionBitMask to its default value, which is to observe collisions for **everything**.

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask):

```
Discussion
When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur. This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero value, this body is affected by the collision. Each body independently chooses whether it wants to be affected by the other body. For example, you might use this to avoid collision calculations that would make negligible changes to a body’s velocity.

The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).
```

So, do:

```
floorNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
```